# How can I move object without redrawing the other objects?

Tags: opengl

I need to move several objects without redrawing other objects.

Comment: I don't know OGL but I think the idea would be to render the other objects as a frame and draw new objects over that frame.

Comment: Are you worried about speed? Don't be, graphics cards can draw millions of objects per second.

Answer (score 1):

Whole scene is redrawn always in MOST 3D engines, so your don't have to worry about moving few objects and letting other stay in place.

Answer (score 1):

When you draw in OpenGL, you draw to a buffer on the graphic card. The buffer do not have a history, it only contains the information for current pixels. In order to move an object without redraw other objects you would not know what to put in the pixels where your object was.

Comment: You still have to rerender every movable object.